# Dynamically created form not submitting, jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

Complete noob here, can someone please tell me why the $pmForm.submit wont work here?  I read that it is most likely an event delegation issue, ive tried rewriting it a ways but still cant get it to work.

Thank you in advance!

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="placehere"></div>
<input id="testbutton" type="submit" value="test"></input>

<script>
var $pmForm = $('#send-pm-message');

        var html ="<div><form id='send-pm-message'><textarea id='pm-message' autocomplete='off' cols='40' rows='1'></textarea><input id='button' type='submit' value='Send'></input></form></div>";

            $("#testbutton").click(function(){
            $("#placehere").append(html);
        });

        $pmForm.submit(function(e){
            alert("I am an alert box!");
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by putting your code in a $( document ).ready() block.
And then change the order of your code.
You will see that when 'var $pmForm = $('#send-pm-message');' is being executed the DOM doesn't have the form yet.
The same goes for your submit action.

I suggest that you put them both after the append, inside the click.

Comment: glad to help!!  :) @Danielsmith

Answer (score 0):

You are actually submiting the div, not the form

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rakesh!

```
<input id="testbutton" type="submit" value="test"></input>  
<div id="placehere"></div>      
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

        var html ="<form id='send-pm-message'><textarea id='pm-message' autocomplete='off' cols='40' rows='1'></textarea><input id='button' type='submit' value='submit'></input></form>";

            $("#testbutton").click(function(){
                $("#placehere").append(html);
                $('#send-pm-message').on('submit',function() {
                alert("I am an alert box!");
                });

            });

});     
</script>
```